# Check if package installed

Tags: bash, if-statement, package

I am using `package-name -v` to see if the output contains "command not found". If the output does contains "command not found", I have to do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
bml_check="$(bml -v)"
echo $bml_check
```

The value of `bml_check` is always showing empty. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because only [`stdout`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is saved on the variable, not [`stderr`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

You have to save both in the variable instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
bml_check="$(bml -v 2>&1)"
echo "bml_check -> $bml_check"
```

Will produce:

```
bml_check -> file.sh: line 2: bml: command not found
```